# Next JS code not compiling after adding latest framer-motion package to project

Tags: node.js, reactjs, next.js, framer-motion

[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H1ajQ.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D2KwO.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5vmmV.png)

Ijust installed the latest Framer motion version in an existing Next JS application, and the code does not compile when the motion tag is added to a div please find more details below and screenshots,

Please note my node version is 18.10.0 and my
Next JS version is 13.1.6
Framer motion version is version 9.0.0
and this issue can be reproduced with these versions

I  have just installed the latest Framer motion version in an existing Next JS application, and the code does not compile when the framer-motion  "motion" tag is added to a div please find more details below and screenshots,

I have also tried downgrading the node versions but this does not resolve, this, is anyone having this same issue with the latest necxt and framer-motion package versions?

Please note my node version is 18.10.0 and my
Next JS version is 13.1.6
Framer motion version is version 9.0.0
and this issue can be reproduced with these versions

Comment: Please do not use code/error images copy/past them with a good formatting instead

Comment: Okay thank you, I would do